# Docking station that connects via both USB 3 and USB C, has various video interface ports

Tags: usb, docking-stations, adapter

I'm looking for a docking station that works with my current laptop (HP Pavilion 15-AY013NR) but will also work with a new laptop. The current one has USB 2/3 ports and no USB C, but I expect the new one to have USB C.

I would like the docking station to support at least two of HDMI, DisplayPort, and VGA.

Or would it be better to get a docking station that just connects to laptop via USB C, but then use an adapter to plug my current laptop into that? If so, which adapter would I want to use?

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this?

Comment: @vab2048 No, sorry. I wish you better luck